# What Version of ChromeDriver Supports HeadlessChrome v60

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am attempting to use Chrome v60.0.3093.0 (Canary) with Selenium.  I would like to also trying using it as a headless implementation.  I was wondering if there is a version of the ChromeDriver that supports v60.x for use with selenium-webdriver v2.53.1
(I am doing this with MAC OS X)

Answer (score 0):

You can found chrome and chromedriver versions compatibility information on official chromedriver download page: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

There is also [version selection guide](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads/version-selection) for future updates. Note that this algorithm can be easily automated like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55254130/1191799).