# How to update chrome driver for windows 10

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, windows-10, python-3.5

Hello I am looking to update my chrome driver to the latest version but cannot find any information on updating the driver - just info on installing it. What do I need to do to update the driver to the latest version?

Comment: Checkout this discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49788257/what-is-default-location-of-chromedriver-and-for-installing-chrome-on-windows/49795348#49795348

Answer (score 7, accepted):

chromedriver is a single self-contained executable file.  Just replace your existing version with a newer one.

1. download the latest version of chromedriver_win32.zip from https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads
2. unzip the file to extract chromedriver.exe
3. replace your existing file with this new executable.

Comment: Where do you find the chromedriver.exe to replace?

Answer (score 9):

Recently I've found that `chromedriver` has almost one-to-one version accordance now (there was three-last-releases support policy for `chromedriver 2.46`). See version selection guide here: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads/version-selection

I've [wrote simple powershell script](https://codeofclimber.ru/2019/getting-chromedriver-updates/) for updating `chromedriver` automatically.

Run this script when you need to update `crhomedriver` (like a build step in CI/CD, just before running selenium web tests):

```bsh
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [string]$ChromeDir="C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
)

if (-Not (Test-Path $ChromeDir -PathType Leaf)) {
  Write-Output "Chrome not found in '$ChromeDir'. Please, install chrome or specify custom chrome location with -ChromeDir argument."
  Exit 1
}

$thisScriptRoot = if ($PSScriptRoot -eq "") { "." } else { $PSScriptRoot }

$chromeDriverRelativeDir = "Selenium"
$chromeDriverDir = $(Join-Path $thisScriptRoot $chromeDriverRelativeDir)
$chromeDriverFileLocation = $(Join-Path $chromeDriverDir "chromedriver.exe")
$chromeVersion = [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($ChromeDir).FileVersion
$chromeMajorVersion = $chromeVersion.split(".")[0]

if (-Not (Test-Path $chromeDriverDir -PathType Container)) {
  New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $chromeDriverDir
}

if (Test-Path $chromeDriverFileLocation -PathType Leaf) {
  # get version of curent chromedriver.exe
  $chromeDriverFileVersion = (& $chromeDriverFileLocation --version)
  $chromeDriverFileVersionHasMatch = $chromeDriverFileVersion -match "ChromeDriver (\d+\.\d+\.\d+(\.\d+)?)"
  $chromeDriverCurrentVersion = $matches[1]

  if (-Not $chromeDriverFileVersionHasMatch) {
    Exit
  }
}
else {
  # if chromedriver.exe not found, will download it
  $chromeDriverCurrentVersion = ''
}

if ($chromeMajorVersion -lt 73) {
  # for chrome versions < 73 will use chromedriver v2.46 (which supports chrome v71-73)
  $chromeDriverExpectedVersion = "2.46"
  $chromeDriverVersionUrl = "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE"
}
else {
  $chromeDriverExpectedVersion = $chromeVersion.split(".")[0..2] -join "."
  $chromeDriverVersionUrl = "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_" + $chromeDriverExpectedVersion
}

$chromeDriverLatestVersion = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $chromeDriverVersionUrl

Write-Output "chrome version:       $chromeVersion"
Write-Output "chromedriver version: $chromeDriverCurrentVersion"
Write-Output "chromedriver latest:  $chromeDriverLatestVersion"

# will update chromedriver.exe if MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH
$needUpdateChromeDriver = $chromeDriverCurrentVersion -ne $chromeDriverLatestVersion
if ($needUpdateChromeDriver) {
  $chromeDriverZipLink = "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/" + $chromeDriverLatestVersion + "/chromedriver_win32.zip"
  Write-Output "Will download $chromeDriverZipLink"

  $chromeDriverZipFileLocation = $(Join-Path $chromeDriverDir "chromedriver_win32.zip")

  Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $chromeDriverZipLink -OutFile $chromeDriverZipFileLocation
  Expand-Archive $chromeDriverZipFileLocation -DestinationPath $(Join-Path $thisScriptRoot $chromeDriverRelativeDir) -Force
  Remove-Item -Path $chromeDriverZipFileLocation -Force
  $chromeDriverFileVersion = (& $chromeDriverFileLocation --version)
  Write-Output "chromedriver updated to version $chromeDriverFileVersion"
}
else {
  Write-Output "chromedriver is actual"
}
```

You can configure relative directory where you need to place `chromedriver` with `$chromeDriverRelativeDir` variable, relatively of script location.

Comment: You don't use `$dir` anywhere in the script.

Comment: Why I need to use $dir? I have used $PSScriptRoot instead

Comment: Then, you don't have to initialize `$dir` here: `if (-Not (Test-Path $chromeDriverDir -PathType Container)) {
  $dir = New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $chromeDriverDir
}` This is redundant, right?

Comment: Yes, I understand now :) I think it was there for debugging purpose. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: In order to run tests after chrome driver is downloaded and extracted, "update-config.json" file should be updated. It has entries to latest and all browser drivers. 
 `# update update-config.json file with new driver info
  $updateConfigPath = $(Join-Path $chromeDriverDir "update-config.json") 
  $a = Get-Content  $updateConfigPath -raw | ConvertFrom-Json
  $a.chrome.last = $(Join-Path $chromeDriverDir "chromedriver.exe")
  $a.chrome.all += $(Join-Path $chromeDriverDir "chromedriver.exe")
  $a | ConvertTo-Json -depth 32| set-content $updateConfigPath`

Comment: The solution worked great on one machine and failed on another that didn't have any chromedriver installed. I surrounded line started with $chromeVersion with try-catch and it worked great.
Try{
    $chromeVersion = [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe").FileVersion
}
Catch
{
    $chromeVersion = "0.0.0"
}

Comment: @user3638751, did you mean case when chrome is not installed on machine, not chromedriver? I've added a check that chrome is installed to script.