# How to fix [1573451709.039][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying... while using chrome version 78 and chrome driver version 78.0.3904.70

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-web-driver

My Chrome browser is updated to version 78 and when I tried to execute any code of automation, it shows the error

```
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
[1573451703.668][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
Nov 11, 2019 11:25:05 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
[1573451709.039][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please add some more information.

Comment: if you have any Chrome or chrome driver instance running, close them and retry again. Also is this in an AWS / Citrix machine?

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
[1573451703.668][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
Nov 11, 2019 11:25:05 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
[1573451709.039][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

---

### Analysis

The first log message:

```
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
```

is part of the startup log when using [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) and is informative in nature.

> You can find a detailed discussion in [How do I protect the ports that chromedriver use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55442679/how-do-i-protect-the-ports-that-chromedriver-use/55450099#55450099)

---

The following log message:

```
[1573451703.668][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
```

indicates there are some **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using.

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to  current levels [JDK 8u222](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v78.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=78.0.3904.70/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 78.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v78.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/78.0.3904.70/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- (*WindowsOS only*) Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- (*LinuxOS only*) [Free Up and Release the Unused/Cached Memory in Ubuntu/Linux Mint](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/10/how-to-free-up-release-unused-cached-memory-in-linux.html) before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed this issue of timeout / Connection reset by changing my code from:

```
public void AfterScenario(Scenario sc) {    
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
        driver = null;
    }
```

to:

```
public void AfterScenario(Scenario sc) {
        driver.quit();
        driver = null;
    }
```

So basically I removed the driver.close() and this fixed my issue. I do not know why this is happening, but experts can explain more...

Answer (score 0):

I had to update to the dev version of chrome 79 and the latest dev version of chromedriver to make it work. Although I've run against other issues with this version, so I don't know if its a good solution.

Comment: How is your answer different from the already published [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58796324/how-to-fix-1573451709-039warning-timed-out-connecting-to-chrome-retrying/58799859#58799859)?