# Scripts Issue or version?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I am trying to execute the script am not getting any error or exception but functionality is not working. can any one suggest me what is the reason for the same.

```
Selenium version: selenium-server-4.0.0-beta-2 version.
chrome supported version: Version 89.0.4389.114
```

Code

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import static org.openqa.selenium.support.locators.RelativeLocator.withTagName;

public class Relative Locator 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Interrupted Exception
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Amitava\\eclipse-workspace\\SeleniumForthEdition\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.rahulshettyacademy.com/angularpractice/");

        WebElement nameEditBox =driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[name='name']"));    
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println(driver.findElement(withTagName("label").above(nameEditBox)).getText());
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        WebElement email =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Email')]"));    
        Thread.sleep(8000);
        System.out.println("selenium-server-4.0.0-beta-2");
        driver.findElement(withTagName("input").below(email)).sendKeys("ami00@gmail.com");
    }

}
```

Console output

```
Starting ChromeDriver 89.0.4389.23 (61b08ee2c50024bab004e48d2b1b083cdbdac579-refs/branch-heads/4389@{#294}) on port 10578
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
[1617949244.583][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
Apr 09, 2021 11:50:53 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Apr 09, 2021 11:50:55 AM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
INFO: Found exact CDP implementation for version 89
Name
selenium-server-4.0.0-beta-2
```

Comment: is your chrome browser launching?

Comment: Please never say but functionality is not working mention the actual results for better response rate. Thank you.

Comment: What do you expect the script to do?

Comment: Yes chrome browser launching and sysout is printing @Sonali

Comment: Objective is passing the email field value by sendkeys() method. @HiranChaudhuri

Comment: I mean Functionality or our scenario is passing the email field value by sendkeys() method, it's not entering the value with out giving any exception. 
But chrome browser launching and sysout value and gettext() method value is printing @SameeraDeSilva

Answer (score 0):

Check these two:

- [How to fix [1573451709.039][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying... while using chrome version 78 and chrome driver version 78.0.3904.70](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58796324/how-to-fix-1573451709-039warning-timed-out-connecting-to-chrome-retrying)
- [When running WebDriver with Chrome browser, getting message, "Only local connections are allowed" even though browser launches properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25080500/when-running-webdriver-with-chrome-browser-getting-message-only-local-connect)

It seems more like versioning issue

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code where you initialize your chrome driver. Looks like it does not receive the incoming messages from web protocol.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.whitelistedIps", "");
```