# How can I execute existing selenium script with ChromeDriver 73 and Chrome version 74 as the backward compatibility was dropped?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am facing some issue with respect to Selenium script. Till now I am using **Chrome v73** and automatically it got updated to **v74**. Now the issue is, code is not executing when I am trying to execute. Throwing below error.
Can some one please suggest how to execute.

```
Starting ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72) on port 36996
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: Chrome version must be between 70 and 73
  (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 2.06 seconds
```

Comment: You can automate downloading up-to-date chromedriver version on windows with simple powershell script as stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55254130/1191799 Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

The **Current Releases** section of [ChromeDriver - WebDriver for Chrome](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) clearly mentions the following:

- If you are using *Chrome version 75*, please download [ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.8](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=75.0.3770.8/)
- If you are using *Chrome version 74*, please download [ChromeDriver 74.0.3729.6](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=74.0.3729.6/)
- If you are using *Chrome version 73*, please download [ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.68](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=73.0.3683.68/)
- For older version of *Chrome*, please see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49796818/webdriverexception-message-service-usr-lib-chromium-browser-chromedriver-unex/49799791#49799791) for the version of ChromeDriver that supports it.

---

### Solution

If you are using *Chrome v74.x* you have to use *ChromeDriver v74.0.3729.6* as a mandatory measure.

---

### ChromeDriver dropping backward compatibility

John Chen (Owner - chromedriver) recently have confirmed that:

> Backward compatibility was dropped from ChromeDriver for a couple of reasons:
>
> - It adds complexity to the code, and is expensive to maintain.
> - It requires an infrastructure to test each build of ChromeDriver against multiple versions of Chrome. There is no such requirement anywhere else inside Chrome, and it became increasingly difficult to convince our build team to maintain such an infrastructure just for ChromeDriver.
>
> I understand this creates difficulty for some of our users, but unfortunately it has become impossible for us to keep supporting the backward compatibility.

---

### Snapshot of Email from John Chen

[image: Chrome_backward]

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [How to work with a specific version of ChromeDriver while Chrome Browser gets updated automatically through Python selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50692358/how-to-work-with-a-specific-version-of-chromedriver-while-chrome-browser-gets-up/50697221#50697221)

Answer (score 2):

Browser version and the driver version for the browser should be in sync.

You can solve the issue by downloading the latest driver from the below link.

From chrome site: 
[Link](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=74.0.3729.6/)
You will need to repeat the task whenever chrome gets an update.

Answer (score 1):

Please download the latest  chrome driver version 74.0.3729.6 from below link https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=74.0.3729.6/)

Answer (score 0):

As you said your browser got updated to v 74 but your framework shall be using chromedriver.exe which is compatible of chrome browser v between 71-73

**Solution:** For chrome browser version 74, please download [ChromeDriver 74.0.3729.6](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=74.0.3729.6/)